# Prove that the integral is finite

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This problem is from a Ph.D Qualifying exam for real analysis.

Suppose that $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m(G)<\infty$, where $G=\mathbb{R}\backslash F$ and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\delta(x)=\inf\{|x-y|:y\in F\}$. Define a function $J(x)$ by $$J(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dy,\:x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Prove that $J(x)<\infty$ a.e. in $F$.

The hint of the problem suggested to show that $\int_F J(x)dx$ is finite, and the result will directly follow.

My attempt: $\int_F J(x)dx= \int_F \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dy dx =\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{F}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dx dy$

Here the integrand is nonnegative, we can interchange the integral by Fubini-Tornelli theorem.

However, I got stuck in calculating the inner integral $\int_{F}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dx$, or simply $\int_{F}\frac{dx}{|x-y|^2}$. How should I calculate this stuff? I attempted to split the integral by $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{|x-y|^2}-\int_{G}\frac{dx}{|x-y|^2}$, but $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{|x-y|^2}$ does not converge, so I gave up.

What approach should I do?

Any hints or advices will help a lot!

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, it was a typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y\in F$, then $\delta(y)=0$. Using Fubini (or Tonneli in fact),
$$\int_F J(x)dx=\int_F\int_{\mathbb R\backslash F}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dydx=\int_{\mathbb R\backslash F}\delta(y)\int_F\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}dxdy.$$

If $y\notin F$, then $d=\delta(y)>0$ and $(y-d,y+d)\cap F=\emptyset$, i.e. $F\subset (-\infty ,y-d]\cup[y+d,\infty )$ and $$\int_{F}\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}dx\leq \int_{-\infty }^{y-d}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}dx+\int_{y+d}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-y)^2}dx=\frac{2}{d}=\frac{2}{\delta(y)}.$$
Therefore, 
$$\int_F J(x)\leq \int_{\mathbb R\backslash F}\delta(y)\frac{2}{\delta(y)}dy=2m(\mathbb R\backslash F)<\infty .$$

Comment: Your third double integral in the second line is missing $\;\delta(y)\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio It doesn't matter since it is the integral wrt x.

Comment: Why $\;y\in G=\Bbb R\setminus F\implies \delta(y)>0\;$ ? $\;G\;$ is open ...

Comment: @DonAntonio : yes you right. I corrected it. Thank you :-)

Comment: @bellcircle I think it does, since then  that equality sign isn't correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio because $\delta(x)=0$ iff $x\in F$.

Comment: @bellcircle That's a circular argument...

Comment: @DonAntonio It is a well-known theorem in topology.

Comment: @bellcircle I don't think so, but of course: I could be wrong. Could you please give me a link or some book where I can check that? And observe $\;F\;$ is **not** compact here.

Comment: @DonAntonio : if $y\in \mathbb R\backslash F$, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $(y-\delta,y+\delta)\subset G$, and thus, $|x-y|\geq \delta$ (notice that $y$ is fixed).

Comment: @Surb That's true indeed, yet I doubt we could prove that $\;\epsilon\;$ works for **all** $\;y\in G\;$ (in fact, that's impossible), so in the limit (i.e., for the $\;\inf$) , we could find the distance is zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio : As I mentioned, $y$ is fixed in $\int_{F}\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}dx\leq \frac{2}{\delta(y)}.$ But indeed, $\delta(y)$ is not bounded away from $0$.

Comment: @Surb I'll tell you why I ask: I did all exactly as you did: $\;\int_F\int_{\Bbb R}=\int_F\int_G\;$ and etc., yet I got stuck in that part of $\;\delta\;$ precisely.

Comment: @DonAntonio By definition of $\delta$, it is obvious that $\delta(y)=0$ if $y\in F$. If $y\notin F$, then $y$ does not belong to the closure of $F$ since $F$ is closed. Therefore, there must be an open ball of $y$ with radius $\epsilon>0$, so $\delta(y)\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: @Surb Well, now I realize that after Tonelli we can take that $\;y\;$ there as constant...great answer indeed ! +1

Comment: @DonAntonio : thank you :-)